# Scala Play Framework 2.6 sealed trait format to Json

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to be able to read and write Json format from a companion object. In the case class I defined the type the `currency` as a sealed trait `Currency` to be able to restrict the values it can be.

I have this case class and its companion object

```
case class Payment(
  id: Long,
  amount: BigDecimal,
  currency: Currency
)

object Payment {
  implicit val paymentFormat = Json.format[Payment]
  val tupled = (this.apply _).tupled
}
```

and this sealed trait

```
sealed trait Currency { def name: String }
case object EUR extends Currency { val name = "eur" }
case object USD extends Currency { val name = "usd" }
case class UnknownCurrency(name: String) extends Currency
```

I want to be able to convert the objects to json doing `Json.toJson(payment)` or reading when it comes as a json. However I am not able because I have some mistake in the paymentFormat. I tried this

```
object Currency {
  implicit object CurrencyFormat extends Format[Currency] {
    implicit def reads(json: JsValue) =
      json match {
        case JsString("eur") => JsSuccess(EUR)
        case JsString("usd") => JsSuccess(USD)
        case _ => JsError("cannot parse it")
      }
    implicit def writes(currency: Currency) = JsString(currency.name.toString)
  }
}
```

When I try to compile the project I get this error

> No instance of Reads is available for models.entities.EUR in the implicit scope

Comment: Isn't currency.toString returning "EUR" instead of "eur" ? I think It may be the mistake you're talking about.
If it is, I will change this comment as an answer, otherwise, could you be a little more precise about what your problem is ? (by giving some example about the result you expect/the result you're currently obtaining)

Comment: @Argurth thank you for reading and the comment. I updated the question, I hope I answered your questions.

Comment: Thanks ! Are you correctly importing the Format instance where  you try to convert EUR to json ? For example ```implicit lazy val currencyFormat: Format[Currency] = Currency.CurrencyFormat``` ?

Comment: @Argurth thank you!!! now it was that, now it is working

Comment: @angusgambina You're welcome ! I posted the comment as an answer so you can mark it as the accepted answer for future users who may face the same issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we finally fixed your problem in the question comments, I post the fixing comment as an answer here :

The following error:

> No instance of Reads is available for models.entities.EUR in the
>   implicit scope

Is fixed by correctly importing the Format instance. Like this for example:

```
implicit lazy val currencyFormat: Format[Currency] = Currency.CurrencyFormat
```

So if someone has a similar problem, please check that you are you correctly importing the Format instance ;)

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this instead:

```
object Currency {

  implicit val reads: Reads[Currency] = Reads {
    case JsString("eur") => JsSuccess(EUR)
    case JsString("usd") => JsSuccess(USD)
    case _ => JsError("cannot parse it")
  }

  implicit val writes: Writes[Currency] = Writes { currency =>
    JsString(currency.name.toString)
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer now it is working with `implicit val paymentFormat = Json.format[Payment]`